# In comic books only, which DC villains has Trigon defeated?

Tags: dc, comics

In the DC comic book universe, which villains has Trigon fought and defeated? Either after having been tricked into the battle, or having sought it out.

What were the circumstances that caused Trigon to fight these particular battles, and if possible, in which story arc or comic did these battles occur?

Comment: Trigon is a world ending threat, there have been several battle in which he was either tricked into fighting a greater scope villain, or where other villains were forced to team up with heroes in order to defeat him, some of these villains were defeated in the process. I'm looking for examples that cover either. These examples range form notable and recent to obscure and classic. An in depth knowledge of the history of this character would help to describe the more obscure events.

Comment: This feels like it's bordering on a list question [*"What are all the books that have X?"*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I'm assuming the number can't be that great though.